# jQuery return value from function

Tags: jquery, function, jquery-mobile, return

I want to return a value from a function, like

```
var value = uberFunction()

uberFunction() {
var institutValues = null
    $.getJSON(jsonFile,function(data) {
        $.each(data.fakultaeten, function(key,value){
            $.each(value.institut[0], function(key1, value1){
                if(value1[0].subID == selectedInstitut) {
                   instititutValues = value1[0]
                   return institutValues
                    } 
            });
        });
    }); 
    return institutValues
}
```

How is that possible? I'm struggling with all the return / return false stuff :(

Comment: Your `institutValues` is not initialized anywhere in your code, it will always return `null`

Comment: Ajax is asynchronous. Your second return statement fires before the ajax call finishes, and the return statement in the callback doesn't do anything. You need to restructure your code to use callbacks or deferred objects.

Comment: sorry, I deleted the line of the the insititutValues, gonna edit that now.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're looking for, but that is how you return a value from a function.

NOTE: If you're having multiple returns, not all of them are executed. After return is hit, the function is exited.

Comment: the first return (inside the IF condition) does not give me any value for "var value = uberFunction()"